# How to create a status check Activity on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I want to create an Activity in `Android 2.3` when the application starts that checks some needed things by the application, then puts a check sign and then the text of the thing that is checked.

For example:

> 1. "GPS Provider enabled" text is shown, if it is enabled, then a check sign appears on its left (if not a stop sign)
> 2. Below the first one, "Network Provider enabled" text is shown, if it is enabled, then a check sign appears on its left (if not a stop
>      sign)

And so on.

I'd like to make it as an animation, if possible. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your activity's `onResume()` write this below code to check if `GPS/Network Provider` enabled of not and depending on that write your other code.

```
    final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        // available
    }
    else
    {
        //not available
    }

    if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        // available
    }
    else
    {
        //not available
    }
```

---

Use ToggelButtons to indicate if they are available or not.